# How to manage Metadata (properties) in Artifactory Git Lfs repository

Tags: artifactory

I want to apply properties on the blobs added in artifactory through Git LFS repository. 
Do we need to automate this through a script or any option available in jFrog for this ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set properties via [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties), [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SettingPropertiesonFiles), or the Artifactory UI.